# update hibernate framework in netbeans

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, plugins

what is the best way to update hibernate in netbeans ide to final 3.5.2 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **[Bug 183327](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183327) - Support for Hibernate 3.5 as a JPA 2 provider**.